# Delphi save error

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

I am trying to save a unit in delphi 2007. But unfortunately i couldn't save it because it continously throwing me the error, which you can find below.
Has somebody encounter the same?[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's an IDE bug. There's not much you can do about it. It's not like Embarcadero are going to ever release an update for that version of Delphi.

Copy the text to the clipboard and then paste into a text editor. Save the file from there. Then restart the IDE, and hope for the best.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have copied the code and restarted the IDE. I had my previous working code.